# Updating reactiveValues from initialized state

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I would like to create a dynamic number of controls (using `renderUI`) and have those controls update a `reactiveValues` object. However, it appears that when the app loads, the `reactiveValues` object is `NULL` so all the values update to `NULL` instead of the desired initial state.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("controls"),
    tableOutput("result")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # Initial state of reactive values
    rv <- reactiveValues(
        my_table = dplyr::starwars %>%
            select(name) %>%
            mutate(checkbox = TRUE) %>%
            sample_n(10)
    )
    
    # Render the dynamic UI 
    output$controls <- renderUI({
        
        lapply(1:nrow(rv$my_table), function(i) {
            fluidRow(
                column(1, checkboxInput(paste0('checkbox',i), value = rv$my_table[[i,"checkbox"]], label = NULL)),
                column(4, textInput(paste0('name',i), value = rv$my_table[[i,"name"]], label = NULL, width = '600'))
            )
        })
        
    })
    
    # Update state of reactive values
    observe({
        checkboxes <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(rv$my_table), function(i) {
            input[[paste0("checkbox", i)]]
        }))
        print(checkboxes) # It seems on load as NULL first before the rv$my_table loads
        names <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(rv$my_table), function(i) {
            input[[paste0("name", i)]]
        }))
        # rv$my_table['checkbox'] <- checkboxes # Uncomment for desired updates
        # rv$my_table$name <- names # Uncomment for desired updates
    })
    
    # Render output
    output$result <- renderTable({
        rv$my_table %>%
            filter(checkbox)
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the inputs (as in `input$checkbox1` etc.) that you are collecting before they are initialized properly in the UI.

A quick fix might be to put `req(input$checkbox1)` at the start of the `observe` block so it doesn't try to read them until the inputs have been populated in the UI.

Comment: This sorta works, however, the default is that `input$checkbox1 == FALSE`. And if I ever uncheck `checkbox1` then it doesn't work. Is there a way to just require `input$checkbox1` has initialized? As a workaround, I added a `actionButton` and made `observer` into an `observeEvent`.

Comment: `req(!is.null(input$checkbox1))` instead will work better.